# parsing .xml file using python :search and copy related data

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I want to copy some data from .xml file based on some search value .
In below xml file I want to search *0xCCB7B836* ( 0xCCB7B836 )and copy data inside that

```
   4e564d2d52656648
   6173685374617274 
   1782af065966579e 
   899885d440d3ad67 
   d04b41b15e2b13c2
```

one more example :
search value `0xECFBBA1A`   and return `0000`

or

search value  `0xA54E2B5A`  and return `30d4`

```
 <MEM_DATA>
  <MEM_SECTOR>
     <MEM_SECTOR_NUMBER>0</MEM_SECTOR_NUMBER>
     <MEM_SECTOR_STATUS>ACTIVE</MEM_SECTOR_STATUS>
     <MEM_SECTOR_STARTADR>0x800000</MEM_SECTOR_STARTADR>
     <MEM_SECTOR_ENDADR>0x0</MEM_SECTOR_ENDADR>
     <MEM_SECTOR_COUNTER>0x1</MEM_SECTOR_COUNTER>
     <MEM_ERASED_MARKER>SET</MEM_ERASED_MARKER>
     <MEM_USED_MARKER>SET</MEM_USED_MARKER>
     <MEM_FULL_MARKER>NOT_SET</MEM_FULL_MARKER>
     <MEM_ERASE_MARKER>NOT_SET</MEM_ERASE_MARKER>
     <MEM_START_MARKER>SET</MEM_START_MARKER>
     <MEM_START_OFFSET>0x1</MEM_START_OFFSET>
     <MEM_CLONE_MARKER>NOT_SET</MEM_CLONE_MARKER>
       <MEM_BLOCK>
         <MEM_BLOCK_ID>0x101</MEM_BLOCK_ID>
         <MEM_BLOCK_NAME>UNKNOWN</MEM_BLOCK_NAME>
         <MEM_BLOCK_STATUS>VALID</MEM_BLOCK_STATUS>
         <MEM_BLOCK_FLAGS>0x0</MEM_BLOCK_FLAGS>
         <MEM_BLOCK_STORAGE>Emulation</MEM_BLOCK_STORAGE>
         <MEM_BLOCK_LEN>0x28</MEM_BLOCK_LEN>
         <MEM_BLOCK_VERSION>0x0</MEM_BLOCK_VERSION>
         <MEM_BLOCK_HEADER_CRC>0xE527</MEM_BLOCK_HEADER_CRC>
         <MEM_BLOCK_CRC>0xCCB7B836</MEM_BLOCK_CRC>
         <MEM_BLOCK_CRC2>None</MEM_BLOCK_CRC2>
         <MEM_BLOCK_DATA> 
           <MEM_PAGE_DATA>4e564d2d52656648</MEM_PAGE_DATA> 
           <MEM_PAGE_DATA>6173685374617274</MEM_PAGE_DATA> 
           <MEM_PAGE_DATA>1782af065966579e</MEM_PAGE_DATA> 
           <MEM_PAGE_DATA>899885d440d3ad67</MEM_PAGE_DATA> 
           <MEM_PAGE_DATA>d04b41b15e2b13c2</MEM_PAGE_DATA> 
         </MEM_BLOCK_DATA>
       </MEM_BLOCK>
       <MEM_BLOCK>
         <MEM_BLOCK_ID>0x20F</MEM_BLOCK_ID>
         <MEM_BLOCK_NAME>UNKNOWN</MEM_BLOCK_NAME>
         <MEM_BLOCK_STATUS>VALID</MEM_BLOCK_STATUS>
         <MEM_BLOCK_FLAGS>0x0</MEM_BLOCK_FLAGS>
         <MEM_BLOCK_STORAGE>Emulation</MEM_BLOCK_STORAGE>
         <MEM_BLOCK_LEN>0x2</MEM_BLOCK_LEN>
         <MEM_BLOCK_VERSION>0x0</MEM_BLOCK_VERSION>
         <MEM_BLOCK_HEADER_CRC>0xE0D2</MEM_BLOCK_HEADER_CRC>
         <MEM_BLOCK_CRC>0xECFBBA1A</MEM_BLOCK_CRC>
         <MEM_BLOCK_CRC2>None</MEM_BLOCK_CRC2>
         <MEM_BLOCK_DATA> 
           <MEM_PAGE_DATA>0000</MEM_PAGE_DATA> 
         </MEM_BLOCK_DATA>
       </MEM_BLOCK>
       <MEM_BLOCK>
         <MEM_BLOCK_ID>0x1F8</MEM_BLOCK_ID>
         <MEM_BLOCK_NAME>UNKNOWN</MEM_BLOCK_NAME>
         <MEM_BLOCK_STATUS>VALID</MEM_BLOCK_STATUS>
         <MEM_BLOCK_FLAGS>0x0</MEM_BLOCK_FLAGS>
         <MEM_BLOCK_STORAGE>Emulation</MEM_BLOCK_STORAGE>
         <MEM_BLOCK_LEN>0x2</MEM_BLOCK_LEN>
         <MEM_BLOCK_VERSION>0x0</MEM_BLOCK_VERSION>
         <MEM_BLOCK_HEADER_CRC>0x1DCC</MEM_BLOCK_HEADER_CRC>
         <MEM_BLOCK_CRC>0xA54E2B5A</MEM_BLOCK_CRC>
         <MEM_BLOCK_CRC2>None</MEM_BLOCK_CRC2>
         <MEM_BLOCK_DATA> 
           <MEM_PAGE_DATA>30d4</MEM_PAGE_DATA> 
         </MEM_BLOCK_DATA>
       </MEM_BLOCK>
  </MEM_SECTOR>
</MEM_DATA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we have this `xml` data inside a file named `test.xml`, you can do something like that:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def search_and_copy(query):
    for child in root.findall("MEM_SECTOR/MEM_BLOCK"):
        if child.find("MEM_BLOCK_CRC").text == query:
            return [item.text for item in child.findall("MEM_BLOCK_DATA/*")]
```

Let's try this `search_and_copy()` function out:

```
>>> search_and_copy("0xCCB7B836")
['4e564d2d52656648', '6173685374617274', '1782af065966579e', '899885d440d3ad67', 'd04b41b15e2b13c2']

>>> search_and_copy("0xA54E2B5A")
['30d4']
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp), with python's [xml etree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and [elementpath](https://elementpath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#installation-and-usage) to write a function to retrieve the data :

Breakdown of the code below (within the `elementpath.Selector`):

1. the first line looks for elements that have our search string

2. The second line `..` goes back one step to get the parent element

3. Proceeding from the parent element, this line searches for  `MEM_PAGE_DATA` within the parent element. This element holds the data we are actually interested in.

4. The rest of the code simply pulls the text from the matches

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import elementpath

#wrapped the shared data into a test.xml file
root = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()

def find_data(search_string):          
    selector = elementpath.Selector(f""".//*[text()='{search_string}'] 
                                        //..
                                        //MEM_PAGE_DATA""")
    #pull text from the match
    result = [entry.text for entry in selector.select(root)]
    return result
```

Test on the strings provided :

```
find_data("0xCCB7B836")

['4e564d2d52656648',
 '6173685374617274',
 '1782af065966579e',
 '899885d440d3ad67',
 'd04b41b15e2b13c2']


find_data("0xECFBBA1A")

['0000']

find_data("0xA54E2B5A")

['30d4']
```